# Error connecting to the service protocol: Exception: No Flutter view is available

Tags: flutter

While running flutter project in android studio first time. Its run the app and gives the error

### Error connecting to the service protocol: Exception: No Flutter view is available

[See error in below](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dEmY7.png)

Comment: Provide more details like platform, OS, version etc.

Comment: can you add this information? `flutter doctor -v`

Comment: After 30 mins it's working correctly......

Comment: How i can close this question